# How to acces local variables in another class

Tags: java

I am making a program that needs a variable from the main method, but when I try to import it by using `Main main = new Main();` I Can't access the variable. How can I use the variable a in another class?

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = 10;
    }  
}

public class SomeClass{
    Main mainclass = new Main();
    main.a;//I get errors when I do this
}
```

Comment: *I get errors when I do this* Because you can't do that. Why do you think they are called **local** variables?

Comment: You should probably read up on how java classes work.

Comment: The point of **local variables** is that they have a restricted scope and lifespan: they are intended to be used for computing a value or achieving some result, and then allowed to pass out of existence. If you want to have variables be accessed from outside of the block in which they are defined, you need to make **instance variables** or **static variables**. 

Additionally, you might want to read up on what **classes**, **instances** and **methods** are in java, as I think you're mixing the the ideas up in a number of ways.

Comment: @BruceWayne May I ask why you unaccepted my perfectly valid answer?

Answer (score 0):

That is why it is called a "local" variable. It is only available locally in the scope it is defined in and you can in no way whatsoever access this variable unless you add some native code and mess with some dirty pointers.

If you need `a` in another class and from the static `main` method you need to make `a` a static member of the class, pulling it outside the local scope like

```
public class Main{
    static int a;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        a = 10;
    }  
}

public class SomeClass{
    Main.a;
}
```

But actually I think you should get a good book about Java and about object oriented development before you proceed, because your example shows that you have not many clues about both of them.

Comment: @BruceWayne May I ask why you unaccepted my perfectly valid answer?